# Neo4j 3.0.1 Cypher query returning collection of one-element collections

Tags: neo4j, cypher

If I issue the query

```
match (x)
where x.property in [40,44]
with collect(distinct x.property) as xproperty
return xproperty
```

I get a collection of values (e.g. [40,44])

However, if I add "x" to the with clause:

```
match (x)
where x.property in [40,44]
with x, collect(distinct x.property) as xproperty
return xproperty
```

I get a collection of one-element collections (e.g. [[40],[44]]

The position of x in the with clause doesn't matter, nor does giving x an alias in the with clause.

Is this a problem in Neo4j or is it a problem with my understanding of how things work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a problem with your understanding of the `COLLECT()` aggregation. When you specify `WITH x, COLLECT(DISTINCT x.property)` you are asking it to create a list of values `x.property` *for each* x. This list is, of course, one element long in each case. Your first query doesn't provide an aggregation key (unaggregated value) like `x`, so it just puts every possible unique value of `x.property` into a single collection, and returns this collection as a single row.

Any time you aggregate during a `RETURN` or `WITH`, remember that you are transforming a list of result rows, and every object or expression carried forward will be included in the rows generated. So if you have two rows with an `x` value, you're going to get two rows after a `WITH` clause that includes `x`. Aggregations operate inside this basic framework by taking every unaggregated field, finding each unique **combination** of values for those fields (called the "aggregate key"), and returning one row for each combination, along with an aggregate calculated from the other fields in the *original rows*.